# yum to treat a package installed by hand as installed through it

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

I've built Emacs 24 and installed it on my FC-17, but if I try to install any package that requires Emacs (such as Pymacs, ECB and so on), all of them will try to install Emacs 23.

I think that my problem is that yum doesn't recognize my Emacs as a suitable substitute (or is at all unaware of its existence). How can I make yum aware of it and not install older Emacs when trying to install Emacs modules?

```
$ yum list installed | grep "emacs"
```

Doesn't give `emacs-common` or anything to that effect, which only confirms my assumption.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two **possible** solutions.

1) You will need to download the package that you want to install and install them via the rpm command using the --nodeps option.

To download the rpms, you should first ensure that you have the "yum-utils" package installed because it contains the "yumdownloader" command.

I don't know the names of the packages that you want to install, but let's say the package name is "something-xyz". Here are the commands to download and install that package:

```
# Download the package
yumdownloader something-xyz

# Test whether emacs is the only dependency.
rpm -Uvh --test something-xyz-7.42-9.noarch.rpm

# If emacs is the only dependency, then install the package
rpm -Uvh --nodeps something-xyz-7.42-9.noarch.rpm
```

If there are other dependencies, than you can try to install via yum if they are not dependent on emacs. Otherwise, you will need to do the same process as above to install them.

2) If all of this does not work with your hand installation of emacs, then the last resort would be to install the emacs version that yum by default wants to install, but invoke your own version of emacs instead of the one yum installs.

Comment: > then there is way for the yum/rpm database to be updated to included it. -- How? :) Yeah, it's cool that Fedora added it to the site, but I'm building from the newer version (the stable one has issues with autocomplete)

Comment: @wvxvw, I've added instructions to my answer that I hope will help.

Comment: sorry, that seems like a confusion... I don't want to download Emacs from Fedora repositories. I have my own patches / I'm using version 24.2.50 (and I need it because of some libraries completely broken in 24.1.X. Or are you saying there' no other way but to first install the old version, then overwrite it with the new one?

Comment: @wvxvw, Okay. Sorry I misunderstood. If I understand, you already have the emacs that you want, but you want to install other emacs-related packages, but you can't because the emacs you installed is not seen by yum. I will revise my answer.

Comment: @wvxvw I mentioned the --nodeps rpm command option, but forgot to include it in my answer. It is there now.